# What is the best way to "wrap text" on a web page

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a HTML page where I am listing pictures of people and their names. If there name is longer than 20 characters I want it to show up on 2 lines instead of one to avoid a lot of empty horizontal space for the people below them

What is the simplest way to make sure to do this.  To be clear, I don't want to break up words in name but rather just break up the words on two lines.

Comment: If you add a css `max-width` property to the element that displays the name, it will grow no longer than that specification.  Then standard HTML wrapping rules will apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the width of the container that holds the name to be smaller or alternatively add some padding. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="name">This is my name</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.name { width: 50px; /* or whatever value works for you */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would rather need to decide what is the maximum width that the name can take. Then,

```
.boxed-name { width: ?? px;text-align: ??; }
```

The main issue with a character counting solution is that it doesn't consider the font family neither the font size. This can lead to serious differences. Also, `mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm` can be longer than `iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii` if the current font is not fixed.